Prove there is no nonzero entire function satisfying the given properties.
I am trying to prove that there is no nonzero entire function that satisfies $f(0)=0$ and $|f(z)| \leq 1$ for $z \in \mathbb{C} ,$ $|z|\geq 1.$ I believe that I can use some combination of the Maximum Modulus Principle and/or Liouville’s Theorem but I cannot seem to piece things together correctly. Thanks in advance!

Liouville's theorem tells you any bounded entire function is constant, and you know $f(0)=0$, so if $f$ is constant, it is the zero function. Since you also know $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for all $z \in\mathbb C$ with $|z|\geq 1$, you will be done if you can show that $f$ has to be bounded on the disk ${z \in \mathbb C: |z|\leq 1}$, and, as you say, the maximum modulus principle might be relevant to the question...

This related question may be helpful: must-an-entire-function-be-bounded-in-any-open-disk-around-the-origin

@krm2233 thank you for the response. Can I get my solution by noting that since f is analytic on the closed disk of radius 1, it attains a maximum on the boundary of the disk (consequence of the Maximum Modulus Principle)? Hence, f is bounded on the entire argand plane?
Therefore, Liouville's Theorem says f is constant (gives the required contradiction).

Or just by continuity the function takes the compact disk to a compact, hence bounded,  set.

This is just putting together what has been said in the comments: Liouville's theorem says that if $f$ is entire, that is, holomorphic on the entire complex plane, then if it bounded it must be constant. Since we known that $f(0)=0$, it follows that if $f$ is bounded, it must be identically zero.
It therefore remains to show that $f$ is bounded. But it is given that $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for all $z$ with $|z|\geq 1$, and hence if $D = \{z \in \mathbb C: |z|\leq 1\}$ is the closed unit disk, we just need to see why $f$ must be bounded on $\text{int}(D)=\{z\in \mathbb C: |z|<1\}$. For this one can either use the maximum modulus principle (since we known $|f(z)|\leq 1$ on the boundary of $D$ this gives us $|f(z)|\leq 1$ inside $D$) or one can simply note that $f$ is a continuous function and $D$ is compact, so that $f(D)$ is a compact, and hence closed and bounded, subset of the complex plane.
